# Rhino Stub not working with Arg<object>.Is.Equal

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a method that takes object as parameter

**Method Signature**

```
  IEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteSql<TResult>(string sql, object param)
```

**Method Call**

```
   string query ="select * from table";
   var data = _Executor.ExecuteSql<ObjectToReturn>(query,
                    new
                    {
                        CustomerID = customerId,
                        AnotherId1= id2,
                        AnotherId2 = id3
                    });
```

**Unit Test**

Mocked it using below example 1 **does NOT work** (does NOT return stubbed return object.)

## 1

```
 _procExecutor.Stub(x => x.ExecuteSql<ObjectToReturn>(Arg<string>.Is.Anything,
                Arg<object>.Is.Equal(new
                {
                    CustomerID = customerId,
                    AnotherId1 = 10,
                    AnotherId2 = 11
                }))).Return(new List<ObjectToReturn>() { new ObjectToReturn() { id = 100 } });
```

this works (does return stubbed return object.)

## 2

```
_procExecutor.Stub(x => x.ExecuteSql<ObjectToReturn>(Arg<string>.Is.Anything,
                Arg<object>.Is.Anything)).Return(new List<ObjectToReturn>() { new ObjectToReturn() { id = 100 } });
```

But I want to make sure that right parameter was passed to right fields so i stubbed my method like #1, but it does not return stubbed return object.

**What am I doing wrong with example 1?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is anonymous arg you can use Matches like this example:

```
IUrlProvider urlProvider = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUrlProvider>();

urlProvider.Stub(u => u.Action(
    Arg<string>.Is.Equal("ValidateCode"),
    Arg<object>.Matches(new PropertiesMatchConstraint(new { code = "spam-and-eggs" })) ))
    .Return("");

public class PropertiesMatchConstraint : AbstractConstraint
{
    private readonly object _equal;

    public PropertiesMatchConstraint(object obj)
    {
        _equal = obj;
    }

    public override bool Eval(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return (_equal == null);
        }
        var equalType = _equal.GetType();
        var objType = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var property in equalType.GetProperties())
        {
            var otherProperty = objType.GetProperty(property.Name);
            if (otherProperty == null || property.GetValue(_equal, null) != otherProperty.GetValue(obj, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            string str = _equal == null ? "null" : _equal.ToString();
            return "equal to " + str;
        }
    }
}
```

Source:

[Arg<object>.Is.Equal with anonymous objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060524/argobject-is-equal-with-anonymous-objects/7594196#7594196)

Comment: Use Expect and no Stub method, that work ?  https://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#ExpectExtensionMethod

Comment: is it possible to do same for nested objects like   var data = _Executor.ExecuteSql<ObjectToReturn>(query,
                    new
                    {
                        CustomerID = new CustomerId{ id=100},
                        AnotherId1= id2,
                        AnotherId2 = id3
                    });